# South Data Migration With OneToOne Key

Tags: python, database, django, django-south

I'm doing a sqlite3 data migration using South. My old schema has the following model for UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    weekOne = models.OneToOneField(WeekOne)
    weekTwo = models.OneToOneField(WeekTwo)
    weekThree = models.OneToOneField(WeekThree)
```

But I have sense added a number of new weeks, i.e., weekFour, weekFive, weekSix, etc. Every week is itself a model, inheriting from a generic Week model. So the basic prototype of a Week model looks like this:

```
class WeekOne(Week):
    name = u'Week One'
    exercises = ['squats', 'lunges', 'stairDaysCount', 'skipStairs']
    # Required benchmarks for given exercises
    squatBenchmark = 1000
    lungeBenchmark = 250
    stairDaysCountBenchmark = 3

    totalGoals = 4
```

My question is, what kind of code should I put in my datamigration code so that I can populate old `UserProfile`s with the additional weeks. I had something like this in mind:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for user in orm.UserProfile.objects.all():
        user.weekFour = orm.WeekFour()
        user.weekFive = orm.weekFive()
        # etc.
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. I get this error when I try to run schema migration:

```
Migration 'my_app:0002_newWeeks' is marked for no-dry-run
```

And later this:

```
DatabaseError: no such column: my_app_userprofile.weekFour_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in the terminal

```
 python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

Then

```
 python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This doesn't work if my app has already created models without the new keys. I.e., I created a user with weeks 1-3 as keys, did a bunch of stuff with those keys and that user, then added weeks 4-9. All of my new users will have all of the weeks, but the old users will have null for weeks 4-9, and the keys are `NOT NULL` keys, so this causes an error.